# In SQL outer joins, what part of the query puts a table on the "left" or "right"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am reading books on outer joins and they reference the "position" of a table in determining whether all of its records will be displayed.

I am confused about how exactly the position (left/right) is determined?

If we consider the standard SQL join

```
Select * FROM
Table_A left outer join Table_B
on Table_A.ID = Table_B.Product_ID
```

What part of this query is determining the position of each Table?

Is it the join part:

```
Table_A left outer join Table_B
```

Where Table_A is on the "left" because it is left of the join word?

Or is it the "=" part:

```
on Table_A.ID = Table_B.Product_ID
```

Where Table_A is on the "left" because it is left of the "=" sign?

Comment: because it is left of the **join keyword**

Answer (score 4):

This makes the difference, so Table name on left side of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is leading one

```
Table_A left outer join Table_B
```

As per the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx), left outer joins include all of the records from the first (left) of two tables, even if there are no matching values for records in the second (right) table.

Answer (score 0):

It's the relative position of the table name in the SQL.

```
table1 left join table2
```

means table 1 is the principle table, where as in a `right join` the table2 would be the principle table.